A fairy tale like story about kids getting lost in the woods and being captured by a "monster"
Country of origin: Unknown, but a western movie. Seen it with Hungarian dubbing.
Date: Don't know, maybe 2006 and older.
It isn't set in present times, it could be as far back as the Middle Ages.
The tone is somewhat dark but not a true horror (maybe PG-13). A boy and his siblings leave their home either of their own will or because they are chased away. They get into various troubles in the forest and towards the end of the film they are captured by a masked monster-like man or humanoid who has a bunch (maybe 8) daughters. They are all crazy cannibals, except for one, who is nice and she falls in love with one of the boys and helps them escape. The masked man kills his daughters in their sleep by accident, because he confuses them with his captives. 
After that, he gives chase to the escaped children.

Related (and possibly duplicate)

I think it might be Little Tomb Thumb (Le Petit Poucet, 2001). It's a French movie based on the fairy tale "Le petit poucet" by Charles Perrault.

Poucet is a kid from a family of numerous children. The parents, too
  poor to feed them, decide to abandon them in the forest. Their, the
  brothers try to find their way out making fantastic ...(IMDB)


















Trailer: 
Youtube
